# Get file list in storagefolder into listview

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to create, read, write, and delete simple text files in a folder. I have a listview in which I want to display the files in the folder whenever the program starts up. Here what I have so far:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    StorageFolder localfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    List<string> files=localfolder.GetFilesAsync().ToString().Split(' ').ToList<string>();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
        item.Tag = file;

        TextList.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

But I get an error in new ListViewItem(filename) saying that it does not contain a constructor that takes one argument. How do I get around it or rewrite the code?

Comment: I think you might need to construct it before without the argument and then add the items in the foreach

Comment: Is this a winforms ListView? The constructor [does exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c277wk5.aspx) if so..

Comment: @Peter there is no need to mention Visual Studio, let alone link to its wikipedia page!

Comment: ListViewItem does have [a constructor that accepts a string argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c277wk5(v=vs.110).aspx). Try commenting out this line, maybe the actual error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (see *[ListViewItem Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem.aspx)*):

```
var item = new ListViewItem();
item.Content = fileName;
```

Comment: I got a System.Exception after replace the code at TextList.Items.Add(item);

Comment: well, what is the exception?

Comment: When I start up the program, VS said An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: @user3417256 sorry, I have no idea on that mess